# Android app shutdown dialog not prevented on some devices

Tags: android, device

I am using the following code to prevent the `shutdown dialog` to be shown on the screen. However, this did not work for some devices. It works on `Samsung Galaxy S4 mini` but not on `htc`. What is wrong with this code?

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if(!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception etc on your log?

Comment: no same code work on samsung but not work on htc

Comment: HTC is a brand and not a device. What do you mean by not on HTC?

Comment: abovre code will still show power of menu how to disable that??

Comment: hi guys did you find a solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with this code?

Nothing. The Samsung Galaxy S4 mini apparently has a bug, where this broadcast affects the shutdown dialog. The shutdown dialog is not [a temporary system dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS) and therefore should not be affected by this broadcast.